# Can any one explain this strange behavior of java HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have used HashMap in Java a lot but has never encountered this behavior. I have to types, **Item** and **ItemGroup**. They are defined as shown in the following codes snippets.

```
public class Item {
    String id;
    float total;
}

public class ItemGroup {
    String keyword;
    int frequency;
    List<Item> items;
}
```

So **ItemGroup** consists of 0..* items. These items have a keyword in common and the keyword appears in the system with some frequency. Now the fun part, I have following method that given a list of items creates a list of groups.

```
public static ItemGroup[] createGroups(Item[] items){
    HashMap<String, ItemGroup> groups = new HashMap<String, ItemGroup>();
    String[] words;

    for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        words = items[i].getId().split(REGEX);

        // Process keywords
        for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){
            if (words[j].isEmpty()) break;

            ItemGroup group = groups.get(words[j]);
            if (group != null){
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(items[i]);
            }else {
                group = EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItemGroup();
                group.setKeyword(words[j]);
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(items[i]);
                groups.put(words[j], group);
            }
        }
    }

    return groups.values().toArray(new ItemGroup[0]);                       
}
```

The part where it gets strange is when adding the item to an itemgroup (the line group.getItems().add(items[i]);). During rehashing the group loses its items in a strange way. Using Debugging I can see that the group contains the item just after the operation but latter on, e.g. when returning the value of the method, all the groups has lost their items.

I tried this:

```
public static ItemGroup[] createGroups(Item[] items){
    HashMap<String, ItemGroup> groups = new HashMap<String, ItemGroup>();
    String[] words;

    for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        words = items[i].getId().split(REGEX);

        // Create a new item based on the current one in the list
        Item item = EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItem();
        item.setId(items[i].getId());
        item.setTotal(items[i].getTotal());

        // Process key words
        for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){
            if (words[j].isEmpty()) break;

            ItemGroup group = groups.get(words[j]);
            if (group != null){
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(item);
            }else {
                group = EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItemGroup();
                group.setKeyword(words[j]);
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(item);
                groups.put(words[j], group);
            }
        }
    }

    return groups.values().toArray(new ItemGroup[0]);                       
}
```

but got the same result. The following solution, however, works just fine.

```
public static ItemGroup[] createGroups(Item[] items){
    HashMap<String, ItemGroup> groups = new HashMap<String, ItemGroup>();
    String[] words;

    for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        words = items[i].getId().split(REGEX);

        // Process key words
        for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){
            if (words[j].isEmpty()) break;

            // Create a new item based on the current one in the list
            Item item = EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItem();
            item.setId(items[i].getId());
            item.setTotal(items[i].getTotal());

            ItemGroup group = groups.get(words[j]);
            if (group != null){
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(item);
            }else {
                group = EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItemGroup();
                group.setKeyword(words[j]);
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(item);
                groups.put(words[j], group);
            }
        }
    }

    return groups.values().toArray(new ItemGroup[0]);                       
}
```

The method EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItemGroup() is implemented as follow:

```
public ItemGroup createItemGroup() {
    ItemGroupImpl itemGroup = new ItemGroupImpl();
    return itemGroup;
}
```

where ItemGroupImpl is the implementation of ItemGroup, e.i. it subclasses the ItemGroup. It is because I use EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework).

Can anyone please explain this behavior (why the ItemGroup objects lose their items)?

Here is the codes for ItemGroup and ItemGroupImpl. The same way looks the codes for Item and ItemImpl.

```
public interface ItemGroup extends EObject {
String getKeyword();

void setKeyword(String value);

int getFrequency();

void setFrequency(int value);

EList<Item> getItems();

void incrementFrequency();
}

public class ItemGroupImpl extends EObjectImpl implements ItemGroup {

protected static final String KEYWORD_EDEFAULT = null;

protected String keyword = KEYWORD_EDEFAULT;

protected static final int FREQUENCY_EDEFAULT = 0;

protected int frequency = FREQUENCY_EDEFAULT;

protected EList<Item> items;

protected ItemGroupImpl() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected EClass eStaticClass() {
    return EconomPackage.Literals.ITEM_GROUP;
}

public String getKeyword() {
    return keyword;
}

public void setKeyword(String newKeyword) {
    String oldKeyword = keyword;
    keyword = newKeyword;
    if (eNotificationRequired())
        eNotify(new ENotificationImpl(this, Notification.SET,
            EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__KEYWORD, oldKeyword, keyword));
}

public int getFrequency() {
    return frequency;
}

public void setFrequency(int newFrequency) {
    int oldFrequency = frequency;
    frequency = newFrequency;
    if (eNotificationRequired())
        eNotify(new ENotificationImpl(this, Notification.SET, 
            EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__FREQUENCY, oldFrequency, frequency));
}

public EList<Item> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = new EObjectContainmentEList<Item>(Item.class, this, 
            EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__ITEMS);
    }
    return items;
}

public void incrementFrequency() {
    this.frequency = getFrequency() + 1;
}

@Override
public NotificationChain eInverseRemove(InternalEObject otherEnd, int featureID, 
            NotificationChain msgs) {
    switch (featureID) {
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__ITEMS:
            return ((InternalEList<?>)getItems()).basicRemove(otherEnd,
             msgs);
    }
    return super.eInverseRemove(otherEnd, featureID, msgs);
}

@Override
public Object eGet(int featureID, boolean resolve, boolean coreType) {
    switch (featureID) {
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__KEYWORD:
            return getKeyword();
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__FREQUENCY:
            return getFrequency();
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__ITEMS:
            return getItems();
    }
    return super.eGet(featureID, resolve, coreType);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void eSet(int featureID, Object newValue) {
    switch (featureID) {
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__KEYWORD:
            setKeyword((String)newValue);
            return;
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__FREQUENCY:
            setFrequency((Integer)newValue);
            return;
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__ITEMS:
            getItems().clear();
            getItems().addAll((Collection<? extends Item>)newValue);
            return;
    }
    super.eSet(featureID, newValue);
}

@Override
public void eUnset(int featureID) {
    switch (featureID) {
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__KEYWORD:
            setKeyword(KEYWORD_EDEFAULT);
            return;
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__FREQUENCY:
            setFrequency(FREQUENCY_EDEFAULT);
            return;
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__ITEMS:
            getItems().clear();
            return;
    }
    super.eUnset(featureID);
}

@Override
public boolean eIsSet(int featureID) {
    switch (featureID) {
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__KEYWORD:
            return KEYWORD_EDEFAULT == null ? keyword != null : 
            !KEYWORD_EDEFAULT.equals(keyword);
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__FREQUENCY:
            return frequency != FREQUENCY_EDEFAULT;
        case EconomPackage.ITEM_GROUP__ITEMS:
            return items != null && !items.isEmpty();
    }
    return super.eIsSet(featureID);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (eIsProxy()) return super.toString();

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    result.append("(keyword: ");
    result.append(keyword);
    result.append(", frequency: ");
    result.append(frequency);
    result.append(')');
    return result.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: You've given us a *lot* of code there. Please cut it down to a short but *complete* example which we can compile and run.

Comment: Please show us the source code for `EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItem` and `EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItemGroup`.

Comment: Don't you have to implement *equals* and *hashCode*?

Comment: Your second version of `createGroups` wouldn't even compile. I suspect you put the item creation inside the first loop instead of before, didn't you?

Comment: @amadeus The map keys are strings, which already implement the needed methods.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. I have added some changes to the question now.

Comment: what is the implementation of the ItemGroup.getItems() method?

Answer (score 0):

In your second set of Code, where is I intialized?

```
 public static ItemGroup[] createGroups(Item[] items){    
  HashMap<String, ItemGroup> groups = new HashMap<String, ItemGroup>(); 
    String[] words; 
     // Create a new item based on the current one in the list
     Item item = EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItem();
     item.setId(items[i].getId());
     item.setTotal(items[i].getTotal());
```

The variable i has not been initialized in this context, so it could be any value (since its not blowing up, I assume you have a global "i" somehwere else in your code, and you are starting your method with that value instaed of 0.

In your code that is working you have i initialized in the method before you access it :

```
   public static ItemGroup[] createGroups(Item[] items){
     HashMap<String, ItemGroup> groups = new HashMap<String, ItemGroup>();
     String[] words;
      for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++){ 
        words = items[i].getId().split(REGEX);
          // Process key words  
       for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){ 
            if (words[j].isEmpty()) break;
```

So, that is my guess as to why you are seeing the behavior you are seeing... ALWAYS INITIALIZE VARIABLES BEFORE ACCESSING THEM.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. Those lines should have been inside the first for-loop. It has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Tell us please what happens in EconomFactory.eINSTANCE.createItemGroup() ? I cannot tell if a unique instance with a unique items List is created each time.

I tried it out with some modifications (I am not currently using Java 6 so can't use String.isEmpty) and assuming regular object creation and it works for me. See below my runnable example (something like which you should post next time you ask a question):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ItemGrouper {

    public static class Item {
        String id;
        float total;

        Item(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    public static class ItemGroup {
        String keyword;
        int frequency;
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<ItemGrouper.Item>();

        public void incrementFrequency() {
            frequency++;
        }

        public List<Item> getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public void setKeyword(String string) {
            keyword = string;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("key=%s freq=%s", keyword, frequency);
        }
    }

    public static ItemGroup[] createGroups(Item[] items) {

        Map<String, ItemGroup> groups = new HashMap<String, ItemGroup>();
        String[] words;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            words = items[i].getId().split(" ");

            // Process keywords
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (words[j].length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                ItemGroup group = groups.get(words[j]);
                if (group == null) {
                    group = new ItemGroup();
                    group.setKeyword(words[j]);
                    groups.put(words[j], group);
                }
                group.incrementFrequency();
                group.getItems().add(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return groups.values().toArray(new ItemGroup[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item[] items = new Item[] {new Item("one two"), new Item("two three")};
        ItemGroup[] itemgroups = createGroups(items);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itemgroups));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[key=one freq=1, key=two freq=2, key=three freq=1]
```

Comment: Ok, I will surely do it next time. If you see the modified answer you will know the implementation of creatItemGroup(). 

I ran your example, it worked fine. I changed my impl. to look more like yours but I get the same behavior. May be it is because of EMF?

Comment: ItemGroupImpl can not be an implementation of ItemGroup since ItemGroup is not an interface. So assuming ItemGroupImpl is actually a subclass, please show us the code. I strongly suspect your answer lies there.

Comment: Yes, ItemGroup is an interface. You can see the code now. But if you are not familiar with EMF then it is gibberish. :-D

Comment: Here's a thought: change 'groups.values().toArray(new ItemGroup[0])' to 'groups.values().toArray(new ItemGroupImpl[0])'